Export Registry specific keys to CSV
I am trying to export 2 specific registry key (REG_SZ) to export through powershell.
Path to the registry: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Intel\PSIS\PSIS_DECODER
Inside the above key, I have many keys, but I want to export specifically 2 keys to CSV and save it. I want the output CSV as below



Name
Value




Key 1
Value 1


Key 2
Value 2



$FindRegPath = HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Intel\PSIS\PSIS_DECODER
$Value1 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $FindRegPath -Name "Key 1"
$Value2 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $FindRegPath -Name "Key 2"
# Create CSV File with header
$outfile = "C:\temp\Outfile.csv"
$newcsv = {} | Select "Name","Value" | Export-Csv $outfile
How can I pass the Key and Value under the Name and Value inside the CSV?

Which keys are you looking to export because most of those will probably be byte[] so in case they're how do you want to represent those byte arrays in CSV ?

$Hash = @{}
$Hash.Add ("Key 1", "Value1")
$Hash.Add ("Key 2", "Value2")
This outputs the result in expected format, however when I export it as CSV, I see the length

There are 2 easy ways you can use to export the values, one is using Get-Item to get the RegistryKey instance and then use GetValue() to get the property values:
$FindRegPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Intel\PSIS\PSIS_DECODER'
$key = Get-Item $FindRegPath
# complete with the actual names here
$keys = 'Key 1', 'Key 2'
$keys | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name  = $_
        Value = $key.GetValue($_)
    }
} | Export-Csv $outfile

The second way is very similar except you use Get-ItemProperty and then get the values via dot notation:
$FindRegPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Intel\PSIS\PSIS_DECODER'
$key = Get-ItemProperty $FindRegPath
# complete with the actual names here
$keys = 'Key 1', 'Key 2'
$keys | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name  = $_
        Value = $key.$_
    }
} | Export-Csv $outfile

In both examples you need to consider that if the value is a byte array (byte[]), you will need to manipulate it in order for it to be properly displayed in your CSV. For example, you could join the bytes with a delimiter:
...
...
$keys | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name  = $_
        Value = $key.GetValue($_) -join ',' # join the bytes with a comma
    }
} | Export-Csv $outfile

